# How to autowire spring.xml defined beans into @Component Beans

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I have a large [Spring](https://spring.io/) Project, whose beans are mostly created via the `@Component` annotation on classes. I'm slowly tring to move the bean definition to the `spring.xml` config file.

I however, get a the following error whenever I try to autowire a bean created in the xml config file into a bean created via the `@Component` annotation.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ComponentBean' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'xmlBean' of bean class [myproject.XmlBean]: Bean property 'xmlBean' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

---

In my spring.xml:

```
<bean id="xmlBean" class="myproject.XmlBean" />
```

---

Trying to autowire beans into `@Component` beans as follows does not work:

```
@Component
class ComponentBean {

    @Autowired
    private XmlBean xmlBean;


    // Bean setters and getters
}
```

Is there a way by which I could marsh up the two, as I slowly port my bean definitions to the `spring.xml` config file.

Comment: I can see the comment for the propety (xmlBean) getter & setter, but have they've been really defined in your class?

Comment: Why? If it works why move to xml (most people do the opposite). Also the fact that you have a field doesn't mean you have a property (check the java bean spec).

Comment: The getters and setters are there. I was only trying to shorten the question